# Family Polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism

What is the current recommended pattern for family polymorphism in Scala?

While experimenting with ways of modeling games, this solution recently emerged:

```
trait Game[G <: Game[G]] {

  type PLAYER <: Player[G]
  type STATE <: State[G]

  def players(): Set[G#PLAYER]

  def startState(): G#STATE
}

trait Player[G <: Game[G]]

trait State[G <: Game[G]] {
  def player(): G#PLAYER
}
```

A specific game (Poker in this example) can be expressed in terms of those traits like so:

```
class Poker() extends Game[Poker] {

  type PLAYER = PokerPlayer
  type STATE = PokerState

  val p1 = new PokerPlayer()

  def players() = Set(p1)

  def startState(): PokerState = ...
}

class PokerPlayer() extends Player[Poker]

class PokerState() extends State[Poker] {
  def player(): PokerPlayer = ...
}
```

I have several questions about this setup:

1. How is `Game[G <: Game[G]]` pronounced *in English*?  What are the names for the roles that `G` and `Game` are playing in this situation? (Meaning specifically in this "recursive" relationship.)
2. Is this a reasonable implementation of "family polymorphism"?  At a high level, my understanding is that this means that Game and it's PLAYER and STATE must vary as a "family".  The takes on family polymorphism in Scala that I've seen elsewhere differ substantially, and I'm not clear on the different tradeoffs:

   - Scala Overview (2006) http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf
   - Martin Kneissl blog (2009) http://www.familie-kneissl.org/Members/martin/blog/family-polymorphism-in-scala
3. Discussion of approaches to family polymorphism involving typeclasses, macros, f-bounded polymorphism, or anything else are welcome.

Comment: In Listing 7.6 of Suereth's "Scala in Depth", a higher-kinded `FileLike` trait is shown that has similar constraints.  That listing is used as an example of what Typeclasses can do better.  [The Typeclass alternative seems much more intuitive than the version it replaces, so I assume I'm missing something fundamental.]

Answer (score 2):

I would question the need to define the classes "outside" of the trait at all. The types `Player` and `State` are already dependent on Game, so you don't need to try to restrict it further.

```
trait Game {
  type Player
  type State <: StateLike

  trait StateLike {
    def player: Player
  }

  def startState: State
}

class Poker extends Game {
  class Player
  class State extends StateLike { ... }
  val startState = new State
}
```

You can use the cake pattern to separate different parts out to different traits/files if you want.

```
trait PokerPlayer extends Game {
  class Player
}
trait PokerState extends Game with PokerPlayer {
  class State extends StateLike { ... }
}
class Poker extends Game with PokerPlayer with PokerState {
  val startState = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this seems much more idiomatic. It's been a while since I posed the question, so I'll re-acquaint myself with the code and your solution soon.

Comment: Can you define even more refined family type like 'TexasPoker', of which 'Player' is a subtype of 'Poker.Player'?